# Can a Cordova App be ported to a website or used as a website?

Tags: cordova

We have a small website that is used for some small administrative tasks by our 400 members (they use it 30 seconds per week). We're planning to turn it into a Mobile App (using Cordova) and continue development there, but a small percentage of them don't have a smart phone.

Is there a possibility to host a Cordova Mobile App also as a website? Or provide these small amount of users with a link to an emulator or something like that? IS that do-able, taking int oaccount it's a very simple user interface and very simple handling?

Thanks a lot and regards,

Pieter

Comment: You can't host a cordova app as website, but you can use a website as input for cordova. If you start your cordova app, you will see you still have an index.html. While coding use feature/cordova detection. See https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/overview/index.html

Answer (score 3):

I can strongly recommend using [Ionic](http://ionicframework.com/) for that use-case. Ionic is built on top of cordova but can also be used for a mobile or desktop website (with *one* codebase!).

Please mind that not all cordova-plugins also offer browser-support so you may have to find solutions wich work for both (or you implement a fallback for browsers).

Also the statement in the comment from Niels is not correct. You can add the browser platfrom (`cordova platform add browser`) to run cordova in a web-browser. Se this [article](https://www.raymondcamden.com/2016/03/22/the-cordova-browser-platform/) for more on this topic.